# Popup Window stopped working after jQuery update

Tags: jquery, popup

I have been using this script for a while now ( originally written by Soh Tanaka but source website is gone) - it pops up a window over a darkened page with a close button that dismisses it and undims the page. It worked fine until I updated jquery to the latest 1.9.1 to implement some new stuff. Now it pops up the window but clicking the close button does not remove it anymore - it just shunts the page in background to top and it seems to add another layer of darkness to the background.

Error console message: **TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$('a.close, #fade').live')** which refers to the last piece of the script: //Close Popups..."

Can anyone help me solve the problem please? Pretty noob to this and more a cut and paste person! Thanx :)

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
    $("document").ready(function() {

        $('a.poplight[href^=#]').click(function() {
        var popID = $(this).attr('rel'); //Get Popup Name
        var popURL = $(this).attr('href'); //Get Popup href to define size

        //Pull Query & Variables from href URL
        var query= popURL.split('?');
        var dim= query[1].split('&');
        var popWidth = dim[0].split('=')[1]; //Gets the first query string value

        //Fade in the Popup and add close button
        $('#' + popID).fadeIn().css({ 'width': Number( popWidth ) }).prepend('<a href="#" class="close"></a>');

        //Define margin for center alignment (vertical   horizontal) - we add 80px to the height/width to accomodate for the padding  and border width defined in the css
        var popMargTop = ($('#' + popID).height() + 80) / 2;
        var popMargLeft = ($('#' + popID).width() + 80) / 2;

        //Apply Margin to Popup
        $('#' + popID).css({
            'margin-top' : -popMargTop,
            'margin-left' : -popMargLeft
        });

        //Fade in Background
        $('body').append('<div id="fade"></div>'); //Add the fade layer to bottom of the body tag.
        $('#fade').css({'filter' : 'alpha(opacity=80)'}).fadeIn(); //Fade in the fade layer - .css({'filter' : 'alpha(opacity=80)'}) is used to fix the IE Bug on fading transparencies 

        return false;
    });

    //Close Popups and Fade Layer
    $('a.close, #fade').live('click', function() { //When clicking on the close or fade layer...
        $('#fade , .popup_block').fadeOut(function() {
            $('#fade, a.close').remove();  //fade them both out
        });
        return false;
    });


        });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the [migration plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/) to solve this problem.

In [jQuery 1.9](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9) a lot of deprecated methods was removed. [jQuery.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is one of the removed methods, you can use [jQuery.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) as the replacement for `live`.

But if you have other dependend libraries which uses these deprecated functionalities then you can use the jQuery [migration plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/) for backward compatibility. It adds almost all the removed functionalities back to jQuery.

In your code, the `live()` event registration can be changed as below

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.close, #fade', function() { //When clicking on the close or fade layer...
    $('#fade , .popup_block').fadeOut(function() {
        $('#fade, a.close').remove();  //fade them both out
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that Arun. I tried changing it to use your code snippet but now the button (close) disappears and the dark overlay disappears but the window still remains?

Comment: Actually scrap that! It works perfectly - my bad - I changed the name of 'popup_block' and forgot about that

Answer (score 0):

`.live` has been removed from 1.9. You can replace this syntax:

```
$('selector').live('event', function(e) {
```

With:

```
$(document).on('event', 'selector', function(e) {
```