# Jquery Popup Window No Longer Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, popup

I had a working popup script that worked great using

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>.
```

I am migrating to bootstrap which has me use

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>.
```

Removing the first and using the second causes the popup to become unclosable. It opens but clicking the close button doesn't work. If I go back to the old version of jquery my bootstrap dropdown navigation stops working. How do I get these two to coexist?

Here is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

//When you click on a link with class of poplight and the href starts with a # 
$('a.poplight[href^=#]').click(function() {
    var popID = $(this).attr('rel'); //Get Popup Name
    var popURL = $(this).attr('href'); //Get Popup href to define size

    //Pull Query & Variables from href URL
    var query= popURL.split('?');
    var dim= query[1].split('&');
    var popWidth = dim[0].split('=')[1]; //Gets the first query string value

    //Fade in the Popup and add close button
    $('#' + popID).fadeIn().css({ 'width': Number( popWidth ) }).prepend('<a href="#" class="close"><img src="http://www.bakercommunications.com/images/close_pop.png" class="btn_close" title="Close Window" alt="Close" /></a>');

    //Define margin for center alignment (vertical + horizontal) - we add 80 to the height/width to accomodate for the padding + border width defined in the css
    var popMargTop = ($('#' + popID).height() + 80) / 2;
    var popMargLeft = ($('#' + popID).width() + 80) / 2;

    //Apply Margin to Popup
    $('#' + popID).css({ 
        'margin-top' : -popMargTop,
        'margin-left' : -popMargLeft
    });

    //Fade in Background
    $('body').append('<div id="fade"></div>'); //Add the fade layer to bottom of the body tag.
    $('#fade').css({'filter' : 'alpha(opacity=80)'}).fadeIn(); //Fade in the fade layer 

    return false;
});


//Close Popups and Fade Layer
$('a.close, #fade').live('click', function() { //When clicking on the close or fade layer...
    $('#fade , .popup_block').fadeOut(function() {
        $('#fade, a.close').remove();  
}); //fade them both out

    return false;
});
});
</script>
```

I did copy the CSS for the popup into bootstrap.css. The formatting is fine, just the close function doesn't seem to run. This is my first time using this site, so hopefully I have explained it clearly enough. Have wasted a day solving the popup problem, only to have it break the top nav.

Comment: Found the answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15217779/popup-window-stopped-working-after-jquery-update?rq=1 

used this line:

    $(document).on('click', 'a.close, #fade', function()

Thank you for the great resource site

Answer (score 1):

[`$.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) was removed in jQuery 1.9, this may be the issue. Try using [`$.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead:

```
$('a.close, #fade').on('click', function() {
```

Comment: Am now using:

    //Close Popups and Fade Layer
 $('a.close, #fade').on('click', function() { //When clicking on the close or fade layer...
    $('#fade , .popup_block').fadeOut(function() {
   $('#fade, a.close').remove();  
 }); //fade them both out
  
  return false;
 });

But still having same problem, will try playing with it some more, thanks

Comment: @user2820910 What very of jQuery is Bootstrap using? There should be a comment at the top of the file.

Comment: @user2820910 can you also open your dev tools (F12) and see what JavaScript errors are being thrown?

Comment: Found the answer here: stackoverflow.com/questions/15217779/… used this line: $(document).on('click', 'a.close, #fade', function() Thank you for the great resource site

Comment: Great to hear, yes the jQuery documentation is exceptional.